# Why do I keep getting an error that the chr() value is out of range?

Tags: python, chr

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
ews = 3
xds = True
while xds:
    password = input("ENTER A 7 DIGIT PASSWORD: ")
    if password == "encrypt":
        xds = False
        def open_file():
            """Open a file for editing."""
            filepath = askopenfilename(
                filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
            )
            if not filepath:
                return
            txt_edit.delete("1.0", END)
            with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
                text = input_file.read()
                txt_edit.insert(END, text)
            window.title(f"Decoder - {filepath}")

        def save_file():
            """Save the current file as a new file."""
            filepath = asksaveasfilename(
                defaultextension=".txt",
                filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")],
            )
            if not filepath:
                return
            with open(filepath, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
                text = txt_edit.get("1.0", END)
                output_file.write(text)
            window.title(f"Decoder - {filepath}")


        def decode(strt, num):
            y = ""
            for i in strt:
                print(i)
                print(ord(i))
                print(ord(i)-num)
                y += chr(ord(i)-num)
            return (y)
        def encode(str, num):
            y = ""
            for i in str:
                y+=chr(ord(i)+num)
            return(y)

        def decode_file(r):
            s = txt_edit.get("1.0", END)
            print(s)
            x = decode(s, r)
            txt_edit.delete("1.0", END)
            txt_edit.insert(END, x)

        def encode_file(r):
            s = txt_edit.get("1.0", END)
            x = encode(s, r)
            txt_edit.delete("1.0", END)
            txt_edit.insert(END, x)
        def clear():
            txt_edit.delete("1.0", END)
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Decoder")
        def enter():
            global ews
            z = e.get()
            if z.isnumeric():
                z = int(z)
                if z<=50000 and z >=1:
                    ews = z
        def test():
            global ews
            encode_file(ews)
        def test2():
            global ews
            decode_file(ews)
        window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=1300, weight=1)
        window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=800, weight=1)

        txt_edit = Text(window)
        frm_buttons = Frame(window, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
        btn_open = Button(frm_buttons, text="Open", command=open_file)
        btn_save = Button(frm_buttons, text="Save As...", command=save_file)
        btn_encode = Button(frm_buttons, text = "Encrypt", command = test)
        btn_decode = Button(frm_buttons, text = "Decrypt", command = test2)
        btn_clear = Button(frm_buttons, text = "Clear", command = clear)
        btn_enter = Button(frm_buttons, text = "ENTER", command = enter)
        l = Label(frm_buttons,text = "ENCRYPTION CODE:", fg = "black")
        e = Entry(frm_buttons)

        btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_save.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady = 5)
        btn_encode.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_decode.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_clear.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        l.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        e.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_enter.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        frm_buttons.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
        txt_edit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        window.mainloop()
    else:
        print("INVALID")
```

Error code:
line 42, in decode
y += chr(ord(i)-num)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

What is happening is that the chr() value is going negative (I tested it with some print statements) but I would like to know how to solve it. I need to add details so the code is basically trying to make a decryption and encryption software.

EDIT:
after modifying this:

```
def enter():
    global ews
    z = e.get()
    if z.isnumeric():
        z = int(z)
        if z<=31 and z >=1:
            ews = z
```

it still has the same error code.

Comment: Looks like you are getting caught with control characters (eg Carraige Return, New Line, Tab etc). The control characters all have a value < 0x20. If your `num` value is greater than 0x20 then your encoding will generate a negative number and cause the ValueError exception.

Comment: how do i fix this? @Tim

Comment: Make sure that num cannot exceed 0x20.

Comment: 0x20 or 20? how do i do that?

Comment: 0x20 is equal to 32 in decimal. Try to modify your "enter()" function. ews variable must be lower than 32.

Comment: it still shows the same error

Comment: I posted the edit in my original post

Comment: What are the result of print(ord(i)-num) line ?

Comment: I get this when testing "hi" Which encrypted to )

Comment: 104, 105, 10, -21 Then the error code showed up on the -21

Comment: why have you 4 values with a 2 characters length str?

Comment: i actually do not know

Comment: it just comes out like that in the console

Comment: Try to print s var and remove not required character. You probably have a "\n" at the end of your line.

Comment: btw im using an encryption value of 31 if you would like to test it to gain info on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you research? Found [plenty of answers for `[python] chr() arg not in range(0x110000)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%29+arg+not+in+range%280x110000%29).

See the [docs for function `chr(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#chr) which requires a postive number as argument:

> The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16). `ValueError` will be raised if `i` is outside that range.

#### Debug the failing statement

To debug your failing statement just add some print outs before to see the inputs:

```
print(f"i: '{i}', ord(i): {ord(i)}, num: {num}")  # debug-print the inputs
print(f"given as arg to chr(): {ord(i)-num}")   # debug-print the expression passed as argument to chr 

y += chr(ord(i)-num)  # will raise a ValueError if ord(i) < num
```

Post such debug print-outputs with your question, because we need such debugging details to reproduce and help you.

#### Further call-stack

Since above failing `decode` and `encode` functions are called with a string `s` and a *subtrahend* given by number `r`

```
def decode_file(r):
    x = decode(s, r)

# or
def encode_file(r):
    x = encode(s, r)
```

Let's figure out what values `r` can be.

Found it in your test-functions:

```
def test():
    global ews
    encode_file(ews)

def test2():
    global ews
    decode_file(ews)
```

Now, either make sure that global variable `ews` is always lower or equal to any char's ASCII code (derived by `ord(i)`), or adjust your expression given to `chr` so that it always results in a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified this:

```
def enter():
    global ews
    z = e.get()
    if z.isnumeric():
        z = int(z)
        if z<=31 and z >=1:
            ews = z
```

So that the max was 10 (which was what I found after some testing) and it had no error code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement so that if whatever is delivered by ord(i) is less than 0 then don't do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).